# React Table with From/To Mappings

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, datatable

I'm trying to make a table in React that is dynamically created with an array of dictionary mappings. Each dictionary has keys id, old, new, and support. Old describes the from entry on the left. New describes the to header at the top. Support is the value that appears at the intersection of both, either Y or N. The problem is that most examples I've seen make use of fixed headers that appear in every item, whereas this is not necessarily the case. I'd also like to sort by ascending version number. Is there anyway to achieve this where headers are dynamic and don't necessarily appear in every item.

[image]

```
const example = {"old": "3.0.10", "new": "3.5.1", "support": "Y"};
```

Comment: Can you make the question more clear? And post what have you tried so far? Possibly a stackblitz/codesandbox to show where you got stuck?

Comment: I think it's very clear as is. Each element in the data has a from/to mapping with a value. How do I assemble such a table? Every table example I've seen has a row based schema in which every key exists in every row.

Comment: Is this information coming as an array or how? You have only shown one record. Plus you have not also shown what you have attempted to solve this? What react code you have for your trials?

Comment: Yes, it's coming from an array, but obviously I'm only going to show one as an example instead of typing the whole thing out. I've tried essentially using lodash to get all the unique headers, but even then you can't really have an empty cell at least not without a key. And you still have to somehow match the dictionaries under the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if that works for you.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-water-y49ih

**SNIPPET (with the same code as the CodeSandbox):**

```js
function App() {
  const example = [
    { old: "3.0.10", new: "3.5.1", support: "Y" },
    { old: "3.0.10", new: "3.5.2", support: "Y" },
    { old: "3.0.10", new: "3.5.3", support: "Y" },
    { old: "3.0.10", new: "3.6.1", support: "N" },
    { old: "3.0.10", new: "3.6.2", support: "Y" },
    { old: "3.0.10", new: "3.7.0", support: "Y" },

    { old: "3.5.1", new: "3.5.2", support: "Y" },
    { old: "3.5.1", new: "3.5.3", support: "Y" },
    { old: "3.5.1", new: "3.6.1", support: "Y" },
    { old: "3.5.1", new: "3.6.2", support: "Y" },
    { old: "3.5.1", new: "3.7.0", support: "Y" },

    { old: "3.5.2", new: "3.5.3", support: "N" },
    { old: "3.5.2", new: "3.6.1", support: "Y" },
    { old: "3.5.2", new: "3.6.2", support: "Y" },
    { old: "3.5.2", new: "3.7.0", support: "Y" },

    { old: "3.5.3", new: "3.6.1", support: "Y" },
    { old: "3.5.3", new: "3.6.2", support: "N" },
    { old: "3.5.3", new: "3.7.0", support: "Y" },

    { old: "3.6.1", new: "3.6.2", support: "Y" },
    { old: "3.6.1", new: "3.7.0", support: "Y" },

    { old: "3.6.2", new: "3.7.0", support: "Y" }
  ];

  // GETTING ROWS EXCLUSIVE VALUES ('old' PROPERTY)
  // STORING INTO rowItems ARRAY AND SORTING ALPHABETICALLY
  let rowItems = [];

  example.forEach(item => {
    if (rowItems.indexOf(item.old) === -1) {
      rowItems.push(item.old);
    }
  });

  rowItems = rowItems.sort();

  // DO THE SAME FOR THE HEADER ITEMS ('new' PROPERTY)

  let headerItems = [];

  example.forEach(item => {
    if (headerItems.indexOf(item.new) === -1) {
      headerItems.push(item.new);
    }
  });

  headerItems = headerItems.sort();

  // NOW WE WILL SEPARATE THE OBJECTS INTO DIFFERENT ARRAYS
  // EACH ARRAY WILL GROUP EVERY OBJECT WITH THE SAME 'old' PROPERTY VALUE
  // THE ARRAYS WILL BE STORED INTO THE NESTED OBJECT separateRowObjects
  // EACH ARRAY WILL BE STORED UNDER ITS CORRESPONDING 'old' KEY

  /* 

    separateRowObjects {
      3.5.1 : [array with all the objects with 'old' === 3.5.1],
      3.5.2 : [array with all the objects with 'old' === 3.5.2],
      and so on...
    }

  */
  const separateRowObjects = {};

  // Initialize arrays for each property
  rowItems.forEach(row => (separateRowObjects[row] = []));

  rowItems.forEach(row => {
    for (let i = 0; i < example.length; i++) {
      if (example[i].old === row) {
        separateRowObjects[row].push(example[i]);
      }
    }
  });

  // GENERATING THE 1ST ROW WITH THE HEADERS
  const tableHeaderItems = headerItems.map(item => <th key={item}>{item}</th>);

  // FUNCTIONS TO MAP ROW AND HEADER AND RETURN THE 'support' VALUE
  function getObject(row, header) {
    const aux = separateRowObjects[row].filter(item => item.new === header);
    if (aux.length > 0) {
      return aux[0].support;
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }

  // AUXILIAR FUNCTION TO GENERATE THE <td>'s FOR THE 'support' VALUES
  function createTds(rowItem) {
    let tdArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < headerItems.length; i++) {
      tdArray.push(<td key={i}>{getObject(rowItem, headerItems[i])}</td>);
    }
    return tdArray;
  }

  // FUNCTION TO GENERATE THE TABLE ROWS <tr>
  const tableRowItems = rowItems.map(item => (
    <tr key={item}>
      <td>{item}</td>
      {createTds(item)}
    </tr>
  ));

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>From/To</th>
          {tableHeaderItems}
        </tr>
        {tableRowItems}
      </table>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
th {
  width: 50px;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Kinda crazy something like this isn't native. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? I supposed your values array is stored under `values`

```js
    const rows = uniq(values.map(v => v.from))
    rows.sort()
    const columns = uniq(values.map(v => v.to))
    columns.sort()

    return (
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>FROM/TO</th>
                    {columns.map(column => (
                        <th key={column}>{column}</th>
                    ))}
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {rows.map(row => {
                    const items = columns.map(col => {
                        const value = values.find(v => v.from === row && v.column === col)
                        if (value) return value.support
                        else return ''
                    })
                    return (
                        <tr>
                            <th>{row}</th>
                            {items.map((item, i) => (
                                <td key={columns[i]}>{item}</td>
                            ))} 
                        </tr>
                    )
                })}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
```